# Configure Dual Monitor on Kali Linux

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, xorg, kali-linux, external-display

I'm trying to configure a second screen for my Kali.
I run it from usb on a Razer Blade 15 and I'm connecting the external monitor by HDMI but the screen remains black. It's like Kali is not recognizing it.
xrandr seems not to recognize any HDMI output. It just see the main monitor and other two devices called DP-0 and DP-1 (I'm trying to figure out what these are). I tried to configure the xorg.conf file but nothing happened. What should I do?

Comment: how have you configured the xorg.conf?

Comment: have already seen this? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92335/how-to-configure-linux-to-output-to-monitor